# find out how I installed Windows 8.1 preview

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 is here.  I'm running the preview.  I don't remember how I installed it.  Microsoft's install instructions vary depending on how I installed the preview.  I don't remember that information.  How can I find out?

Comment: There are only two ways to install the preview use the installation media which you downloaded or do it through the Windows Store.  You should backup your personal files before you upgrade to the GA/RTM build you will need to reinstall all applications that are installed when you do so.  The preview will expire.

Answer (score 0):

The Preview was installed via the Windows Store when you installed the beta version of the update [kb2871389](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871389)